# Where to download ArcSDE for SQL Server?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, installation, license

I have ArcSDE for SQL Server 2008 R2.

I want to install ArcSDE for another version of SQL Server.

I want to download the ArcSDE software but I cannot find it in search.

Where can I find it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Esri incorporated ArcSDE into [ArcGIS Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ArcGIS_Server) with the release of ArcGIS 9.2. In order to deploy ArcSDE technology as an enterprise geodatabase you must have, or be prepared to purchase, an ArcGIS Server license.  Since the introduction of ArcGIS 10.0, the actual [enterprise geodatabase installer lives within ArcPy](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000162000000), and can be invoked either as an ArcToolbox tool or directly from Python.

Application server binary ("ArcSDE server") media is available from the same location as the ArcGIS for Server media (via download or disc).  There are separate installers for each of the supported RDBMS; simply choose the application server for the installed RDBMS.  There is only one application server media bundle per RDBMS product (the same media could be used for your other SQL-Server instance, provided it is [supported by that build of ArcGIS](http://support.esri.com/en/content/system-requirements))

If you are already licensed for Esri products you can obtain your software from [My Esri](https://my.esri.com/welcome), which was formerly Esri Customer Care Portal, where all your licensed software is available for download.

If you are not already licensed for Esri products you can [contact Esri](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgis-for-desktop/pricing) to purchase licenses or [obtain trial versions](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgis-for-desktop/free-trial).

ArcGIS Server can be difficult to setup properly; Esri used to and may still (for a reasonable price) install and configure your Server products if required.